# Google maps appearing grey screen angularjs

Tags: java, google-maps

I keep getting this error:

```
 A message body reader for Java class com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition, and Java type class com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition, and MIME media type multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarytc5htd89UiRycrMp was not found
```

I am trying to upload file using [this resource](https://avaldes.com/file-upload-example-using-restful-web-service-with-jax-rs-and-jersey/). I have added all the required jars and xml dependencies.

Comment: so what changed? Some background information would help. Have you tried rolling back to version that was working?

Comment: It's possible that google maps itself did an upgrade. Suggest you check their version logs. Also not sure why you need all the extra map files. In my past experience with google maps all I ever needed was the main api script and it loaded anything else that was needed